# reading from an array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, textbox

I am really close to getting this to work correctly, but I am just missing something.  It's probably quite simple.  I'm very new to C#.  I have a textbox called `txtState` where you input a city(I know) to see if you have visited this city. It outputs a response to another textbox `txtAnswer` when you click the `btnVisited` button.  Right now It's just inputting whatever I input into the `txtState` box and saying it's the 0 position in the array.  I forgot to mention I need to include what position in the array this city is, and output that to the textbox as well.  Here is my code:

```
namespace Test
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtAnswer.Text = "";
        txtState.Text = "";
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void btnVisited_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] CityName = {"Columbus", "Bloomington", "Indianapolis",
        "Fort Wayne", "Greensburg", "Gary", "Chicago", "Atlanta", "Las Vegas"};
        bool visitedbool;
        int subscript;
        subscript = 0;
        visitedbool = false;
        string QueryCity;
        QueryCity = txtState.Text.ToUpper();
        do 
        {
            subscript += 0;
            if (subscript == 0)
                txtAnswer.Text = "You have visited" + " " + QueryCity + " " + "It is the" + " " + subscript + " " + "city you have visited.";

            else if (subscript == 1)
                txtAnswer.Text = "You have visited" + " " + QueryCity + " " + "It is the" + " " + subscript + " " + "st city you have visited.";

            else if (subscript == 2)
                txtAnswer.Text = "You have visited" + " " + QueryCity + " " + "It is the" + " " + subscript + " " + "nd city you have visited.";

            else if (subscript == 3)
                txtAnswer.Text = "You have visited" + " " + QueryCity + " " + "It is the" + " " + subscript + " " + "rd city you have visited.";

            else if (subscript == 4 - 8)
                txtAnswer.Text = "You have visited" + " " + QueryCity + " " + "It is the" + " " + subscript + " " + "th city you have visited.";

            else
                txtAnswer.Text = "You have not visited this city.";
        }
        while (visitedbool == true);       
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the line `subscript += 0;`? What do you think this line does?

Comment: Use a list, or even better a "Dictionary" for this. No need to use arrays to do lookups in C#. http://www.dotnetperls.com/list, http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary

Comment: I'm trying to increment the position in the array by 1, so that Columbus is the 0 position in the output, and Bloomington is 1 in the output textbox.  Does my explanation make sense?

Comment: subscript += 0 will add zero to subscript!

Comment: @Cort3z Like I said, I'm new to C# and I'm not familiar with the list or "Dictionary". Could you give me some quick and dirty examples, or is it too complex to be explained quickly?

Comment: Also, your loop won't ever finish.

Comment: @LeeTaylor Thanks for the input.  I changed it to subscript +=1, but it's still not pulling the values from my array.  I think I need to reference the CityName in my code somewhere, but I'm not sure where to put it in.

Comment: @LeeTaylor I tried setting the while to (vistedbool == false);, but the application would just hang when I input values.

Comment: visitedbool isn't being updated, so either the loop will be infinite, or fall through on the first iteration. Neither seems useful.

Comment: @JasonD I wasn't sure if I needed to somehow update the visitedbool, or reference the array CityName, but I knew it wasn't reading my array for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

**First issue with your code:**

This won't work: `else if (subscript == 4 - 8)`

Try this instead: `else if (subscript >= 4 && subscript <= 8)`

**Second:**

`subscript += 0;` is the same as `subscript = subscript + 0;`

If you're using subscript as some kind of counter it won't work since you're just adding `0`

**Third:**

`visitedbool` will always be `false`. Your loop will only run once because you never set `visitedbool` to `true`

Comment: I changed my code to the following, but the form crashes when I click the btnVisited. visitedbool = true; and the else if statement as you have above.  Also, I've changed my subscript +=0 to subscript +=1

Comment: What do you mean with *the form crashes*? Are you getting an exception?

Comment: @Mr_Green It doesn't do anything when I debug it.  It just hangs there. I can't click the close or minimize buttons.  I have to do and end task in the task manager, it says "not responding."

Comment: @DerekPike It freezes because you have an infinite loop.

Comment: That's because you created an infinite loop. You never change the value of `visitedbool`, therefore it won't ever exit the loop.

Comment: Sorry, I am very new to c#. How do I go about changing the value of visitebool?

Comment: @DerekPike Maybe you should start with a less complex example to make yourself familiar with C#. It seems like you still have to work on some basic understanding. You have lots of issues in your code and are making your life pretty difficult trying to figure out what's wrong there.

Comment: You are most correct when you say I need to work on some basic understanding; however, this is a project for school that I am trying to complete. We "learned" C# last semester using the term learned very loosely.  I'm in an asp.net class this semester trying to add asp.net to c#.  Our teacher gave us this project as a refresher on c#.

Comment: @DerekPike to be honest you probably should grab your textbooks from last semester and go through the basics of programming once again. The code you posted has more than just one or two issues.

Comment: Since I do not have my c# book from last semester, someone was giving away a c++ for dummies book.  I figured I could go through that and learn the logic behind coding, and just change the syntax to code in c#.

Comment: @DerekPike C++ is not C#. Get yourself a basic book on C#. Translating C++ to C# is very difficult, even for most experienced developers.

Comment: Ok, I will browse Amazon and see what I can find.  Thanks for the advice.

Comment: I have a C# for dummies book on it's way.